# How to solve $y=x \left(\frac{dy}{dx} + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3\right)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y=x \left(\frac{dy}{dx} + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3\right)$$

Now for this, I write $ \frac{dy}{dx} = P $
And differentiate the given equation to get $\frac{dP}{dx} = \frac{-P^3}{1+3P^2} $
This gives $-\ln x = 3\ln P- \frac{P^{-2}}{2}$

Now what ..?? The answer given is..

> $y = 0 $ & $y = P^{-3}e^{\frac{P^2}{2}}(P+P^3)$

Comment: Just solve for $x$ from your final equation and sub back in. You know the trivial solution is y is a constant.

Comment: @Chinny84 Why is the trivial solution y = constant there ?? Actually I have only been taught about basic differential equations and of first degree order one type... I was just told for higher power just write \frac{dy}{dx} = P , differentiate and solve. If you could provide a more elaborate solution, it would be really helpful. Thank You :)

Comment: For the nonzero solution, is the goal to write $y$ as a function of $P$ and not $x$? If so then you just use your attempt thus far and then solve for x in the first equation and substitute it into your attempt. Then you can rearrange to get $y$ as a function of $P$.

Comment: @Ian But y= 0 case ?? . Where does taht come from ??

Comment: @DivMit it is trivial since you know that a we have $y = x\frac{dy}{dx}F(P)$ and we have a possible solution $y = \alpha \implies y' = 0$ thus $\alpha = x\cdot 0 \cdot F(0)$ or $\alpha = 0 = y$.

Comment: but this is true for any ODE where each term has a dependence on $y$ or the derivatives. not really interesting, as sometimes one can not even reach $y=0$ (which I guess is interesting in itself.)

Comment: You get $y=0$ by guessing, essentially, which you have to do because at some point in solving the nonzero case you have to divide by something and can't be sure whether it is zero.

Comment: The answer given is wrong. It should be $y = \exp[1/(2P^2)](1+1/P^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, I said "$y$ as a function of $P$" but it should have been "$x$ as a function of $P$", or alternately "an implicit relationship between $P$ and $x$".

Comment: @Ian Thank You .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is probably wrong. Moreover you missed constant of integration. You can proceed as follows
$$\frac{dP}{dx}=-\frac{P^3}{x(1+3P^2)}$$
$$\frac{dx}{x}=-\frac{1+3P^2}{P^3}dP$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{x}=-\int \frac{1}{P^3}dP-3\int \frac{1}{P}dP$$
$$\ln x=-\frac{P^{-2}}{-2}-3\ln P+c$$
$$\ln x=\frac{1}{2P^2}+\ln P^{-3}+c$$
$$\ln x=\ln e^{\frac{1}{2P^2}}+\ln P^{-3}+\ln K$$
$$\ln x=\ln \left(KP^{-3}e^{\frac{1}{2P^2}}\right)$$
$$x=KP^{-3}e^{\frac{1}{2P^2}}$$
Where K is some positive real number.

Hope it helps

Comment: In the original equation, $dP/dx = -P^3/[x(1+3P^2)]$. OP did that calculation wrong.

Comment: Yes, absolutely right but OP missed constant of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Another method of solving this equation is using substitution $y=u(x)x$. It gives you $$ ux = x\Big(\big(u+x\frac{du}{dx}\big) + \big(u+x\frac{du}{dx}\big)^3\Big)$$
$$ 0 = x\frac{du}{dx} + \big(u+x\frac{du}{dx}\big)^3$$
$$ u = -x \frac{du}{dx} - \big(x\frac{du}{dx}\big)^\frac13$$
Let $f(z) := -z-z^\frac13$. We have
$$ u = f(x \frac{du}{dx})$$
$$ f^{-1}(u) = x\frac{du}{dx} $$
$$ \frac{du}{f^{-1}(u)} = \frac{dx}{x}$$
$$ \int \frac{du}{f^{-1}(u)} = \int \frac{dx}{x}$$
we have $$ \int \frac{du}{f^{-1}(u)} = \bigg[\int \frac{f'(w)dw}{w}\bigg]_{w=f^{-1}(u)} = \bigg[\int \frac{(-1-\frac13 w^{-\frac23})dw}{w}\bigg]_{w=f^{-1}(u)} = \\ = \Big[-\ln w + \frac12 w^{-\frac23} + C\Big]_{w=f^{-1}(u)}$$
so $$ -\ln \big(f^{-1}(u)\big) + \frac12\big(f^{-1}(u)\big)^{-\frac23} = \ln x  + C$$
Let $g(z)=-\ln z+\frac12 z^{-\frac23}$. We have
$$ f^{-1}(u)= g^{-1}(\ln x + C)$$
$$ u = f\big(g^{-1}(\ln x + C)\big) = -\big(g^{-1}(\ln x + C)\big) - \big(g^{-1}(\ln x + C)\big)^\frac13$$
$$ y = -x \Big(\big(g^{-1}(\ln x + C)\big) + \big(g^{-1}(\ln x + C)\big)^\frac13\Big)$$
Unfortunately, function $g^{-1}(z)$ cannot be expressed using elementary functions.